# Send data to multiple channels in succession

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have the following scenario: A function that is called every minute and each time it is called it attempts to send data to multiple defined channels as such.

```
var chan1 = make(chan bool)
var chan2 = make(chan bool)
var chan3 = make(chan bool)

go func() {
 for {
  <-time.After(1* time.Minute)
  chan1 <- true
  chan2 <- false
  chan3 <- true
 }
}()
```

Then in three separate go routines each channel is read via a `select` like so.

```
go func() {
 var myVar bool

 select {
   case <- chan1: //or chan2, chan3 etc...
     myVar = true
   default:
     myVar = false
}()
```

The issue is only `chan1` receives the data from the first time based loop. So what appears to be occurring is the sending of data is blocked for all subsequent channels until the first channel is read. How would I correct this?

Comment: Use a buffered channel or run the send async (`go func() { chan1 <- true }()`)

Comment: Thanks the Async does the trick, I will look at buffered channels though since the async looks a little messy.

Comment: Why the downvote on this question? It seems perfectly valid...

Comment: Reposted as an answer with some example code. HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [buffered channel](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3):

```
var chan1 = make(chan bool, 1)
var chan2 = make(chan bool, 1)
var chan3 = make(chan bool, 1)
```

Or run the send [asynchronously](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1):

```
go func() {
    chan1 <- true
}()
```